# Mongoose: Limiting Query result in MongoDB for Pagination

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pagination

I got a collection with 1k documents and I want to paginate them, by limiting it with only 16 docs pr page, then use the skip method. How would I accomplish that with a URL query?

**Right now my route looks like this, but doesn't work** - 
I can query: localhost:3000/api/feed?isActive=true, but I cant limit it with localhost:3000/api/feed?isActive=true&page=16, as I want.

```
router.get('/feed', function(req, res, next) {
  var params = req.query;
  var page = req.query.page;
  var pagesize = 16

  Feed.find(params)
    .sort({'date' : 1})
    .skip(pagesize*(page-1))
    .limit(pagesize)
    .exec(function(err, result) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        result: result
      })
    });
})
```

Comment: Because you're using `req.query.page` and not `req.query.limit`?

Comment: Hm, I dont think so - It seems to accept the query: /api/feed?isActive=true&page=16 fine but it dosen't return anything :/

Comment: I was referring to the use of `&limit=16` in your original question, before you edited it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using all query string parameters as properties to query:

```
var params = req.query;
```

Because you're now adding a new query string parameter `page`, this will affect your query. In your URL example, the query becomes this:

```
{
  isActive : 'true',
  page     : '16'
}
```

You should remove that parameter before using `req.query` as a query document:

```
var page = req.query.page;
delete req.query.page;

var params = req.query;
```